# Is it a good practice to clear audio metadata? If yes, how?

Tags: azure, audio

According to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-inject-executable-malicious-code-into-pdf-jpeg-mp3-etc metadata can contain malicious code

I am working on an app that handles sensitive sales information, and there is a part where the user can upload a sound for a personal jingle (won't give more details about that)
A manager user can edit and download the sound file, we are using html5 audio tag

1. Should I clean the audio file metadata?
2. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

The project uses C# as back-end, Azure services, HTML5 with js.

Comment: Generally you could extract/sanitize,but how to do it is more of a stack overflow question.